Android Studio does not read library from github
I use Android Studio version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64. and i have problem with add libraries that are not from Android itself  for example libraries  are github . this really made it impossible for me .
my build.gradle(poroje) is
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.5.1" apply false
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.51.1" apply false
}


and my build.gradle(app)
import com.github.javaparser.printer.lexicalpreservation.DifferenceElement.kept

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
   id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}



android {
    namespace = "com.example.marriage"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.marriage"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding=true
        viewBinding=true;
    }

}


dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("com.raycoarana.codeinputview:codeinputview:2.1.5")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.7.7")
    implementation ("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.7.7")
    implementation ("com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0")
    implementation ("androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0")

    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.51.1")
    annotationProcessor ("com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.51.1")
    implementation ("com.github.shuhart:stepview:1.5.1")
    implementation ("io.github.chaosleung:pinview:1.4.4")
    implementation ("com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1")
    // Room components
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1")
    annotationProcessor ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1") // Use kapt for Kotlin
    implementation("com.github.MohammedAlaaMorsi:RangeSeekBar:1.0.6")

    implementation ("com.github.andreasagap:LoadingButtonLibrary:v1.0")

}
    

and my  setting.gradle(app)

pluginManagement {
    repositories {

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }

    }

}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
    }

}


rootProject.name = "Marriage"
include(":app")

but when i add libraries that are not from Android itself . it doesn't accept those . either it doesn't allow to add them at all or if it adds them ,it doesn't recognize them when i want to use them

You forgot to post the error message you get or at least mention the library that can  it be resolved.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
